# Excel 2016 - locked for editing features vanished?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, editing, sharepoint

I'm not sure when it started but our workers cannot see the menu below now.

"oo.xlsx is locked for editing
by 'another user'.
Open "Read-Only" or click "Notify" to open read-only and receive notification
when the document is no longer in use."

We don't suggest co-authoring so above default option was really helpful. 
However, I realize that after we updated the Excel 2016 to current version, (8326.2048) the files converted to co-authoring-enabled and I could not find any option to enable the 'locked for editing' option.

We uploaded the excel files on the SharePoint online site (we use 365 BP) for the file sharing.

It should not be a option as check out/in.

Is there any option you know about it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the version number of an Insider Fast build. In that version, AutoSave and co-authoring are enabled by default. You should see a slider for AutoSave above the File tab. This will show for any file stored in the cloud, i.e. OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, SharePoint online, etc.

Turn AutoSave off. Then people can open the workbook, and start making changes. Once they try to save the file, they get a message like this:

[image]

The fact that this message only appears when the user attempts to save the file, and not when they open the file has already caused a lot of frowns in the community. After all, they could have already spent an hour making changes before attempting to save, and only then learn that the file is locked.

Until Microsoft fixes that behaviour you may want to try and save the file immediately after opening. If you don't get a message that the file is locked, it's all yours.

I suggest that you use the smile/frown feedback to send your feedback about this behaviour directly to the Excel team at Microsoft. They really do read that.

I personally don't like the automatic AutoSave and co-authoring and would be happy to see many more people express their opinion.